# Why would a script tag run correctly if embedded in HTML, but not generated by aspx?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

If I embed a special control (a prescription search box widget by rxwiki) inside a simple html file like so:

```
<html>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" id="rxwiki_sw_js" src="http://www.rxwiki.com/rune/search/widget?utm_medium=search_widget&utm_source=795f9976-4258-5fc8-A659-e5c31cccf791">
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When this page is rendered, the appropriate search control appears and operates.

However, if I embed that same element into a working aspx page it does not. Instead I just get an edit box embedded in a blank border that looks about the same size as the original image.

If I put the same code in the master page it does render, but putting it in the master page isn't an option for me.

Suggestions?

Comment: Search for error messages at the javascript console

Comment: Look at the source from the resulting HTML (in the browser). Does the script element appear properly?

Comment: Yeah, in fact I copied and pasted the resulting script element from the rendered aspx page to create the html example. That's what's making this really odd. Hmmm maybe I should try to embed it on a different aspx from the one I'm trying to. Maybe there's some page load handler or something that's messing things up.

Comment: It's unlikely it's any server code that is messing with your control. It's more likely to be something client-side, maybe another script interfering. Try using the browser script debugger to check what is being run.

Comment: Does the Javascript operate on HTML elements by ID? If so, make sure the IDs are what you expect. Asp.net does funny things with ID names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script tries to create a  like below:

```
<form id="rxwikiSearch" target="_blank" action="http://www.rxwiki.com/search" method="get" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

When you use a masterpage, it has a form element and contents are rendered inside it. In the content if you have that script, it tries to render another form inside master page's form, which is not allowed.

I have tested with keeping a contentplaceholder at masterpage's head (which is generated by wizard) and putting the script at content page like below:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
     <script type="text/javascript" id="rxwiki_sw_js" src="http://www.rxwiki.com/rune/search/widget?utm_medium=search_widget&utm_source=795f9976-4258-5fc8-A659-e5c31cccf791">
  </script>
</asp:Content>
```

And it is working fine!

Comment: Ah, this is a great explanation! Thanks!